# How can I send image from client to server node js react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create upload profile image method that help user upload their profile picture on website but I am having trouble with I dont know how to send the image from client to server and make those image store on cloudinary or firebase.

My routes look like this:
*ProfileAPI.js*

```
    const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();
    const { body, param } = require("express-validator");
    const { catchErrors } = require("../errors/errorHandlers");
    const multer = require('multer');
    const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
    
    const upload_dir = './images';
    
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, upload_dir);
      },
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `${uuidv4()}-${file.filename.toLowerCase}`);
      }
    });
    
    const upload = multer({
      storage: storage,
      fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (
          file.mimetype == 'image/png' ||
          file.mimetype == 'image/jpg' ||
          file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg'
        ) {
          cb(null, true);
        } else {
          cb(null, false);
          return cb(new Error('Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!'));
        }
      }
    });
const {
  getUserProfile,
  getUsersPublicProfile,
  lookUpId,
  updateUserProfile,
  updateUserEmail,
  deleteUserProfile,
  // deleteUserSkill,
  addPlayersProfile,
  getCreatedPlayers,
  updatePlayersProfile,
  deleteUserCreatedPlayer,
} = require("./profilesController");
    
    router.post(
      "/upload",
      upload.single('profileImg'),
      updateUserProfile
    );
```

So key points are the setup of storage which tells where to upload + the file filter in upload, right?

And the route.post which will `upload.single('profileImg'), right? the route will include my controller for updateUserProfile which can be found here:
*profilesController.js*

```
exports.updateUserProfile = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.session.passport.user.id;
  // This array will contain all the update functions to run.
  const updates = [];

  // If a gravatar url has not been generated, do it now.
  const pictureValue = gravatar.url(
    req.body.email,
    { s: "100", r: "pg", d: "retro" },
    true
  );

  const payload = {
    fullname: req.body.fullname,
    location: req.body.location,
    webpage: req.body.webpage,
    linkedin: req.body.linkedin,
    institution: req.body.institution,
    bio: req.body.bio,
    major: req.body.major,
    mergedTo: userId,
    picture: pictureValue,
    skillone: req.body.skillone,
    skilltwo: req.body.skilltwo,
    skillthree: req.body.skillthree
  };
}
```

So now to the frontend code (react.js):

This is the form I am loading in my react app:

*UserProfile.js*

```
const UserProfile = (serverUserData) => {
  const appState = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const { currentUser } = appState;
  const { email, picture, name } = currentUser;
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(false);

  const checkVerificationData = () => {
    axios.get("/api/v1/profiles/profile").then((res) => {
      const { data } = res;   
      if (data.verifiedDT) {
        setIsVerified(data.verifiedDT);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkVerificationData();
  }, [isVerified]);


    // Upload user avatar function
  const [imageSelected, setImageSelected] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('profileImg', imageSelected);

    axios
      .post(`/upload`, formData)
      .then(() => console.log("success"))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  const onFileChange = (e) => {
    setImageSelected({ profileImg: e.target.files[0] });
  };
    };

 const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12}
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center"
        spacing={4}>
        <Grid item>
          <Grid item>
            <UserCard
              picture={currentUser.picture}
              userEmail={email}
              name={name}
              isVerified={isVerified}
              handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
              onFileChange={onFileChange}
            />
            <br />
          </Grid>
```

and here is where user can upload their profile photo:
*UserCard.js*

```
  {picture ? (
    <div>
      <Avatar
        src={picture}
        alt="Avatar"
        className="avatar--profile_image"
      />  
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={onFileChange}
      />  
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <AccountCircleIcon className="avatar--profile_image" />
  )}
```

So when entering things and hitting the Add Button my api states that req.file is undefined and I cannot find out why.

Can anyone help me drilling down the error?

Comment: To upload files, you need to use  `contentType: "multipart/form-data"` in `axios` post request first paramenter.

Comment: How do I write it? @AmilaSenadheera

Comment: Did you add `body-parser` to your express app. Other things seem okay to me

Comment: Yes I did. Would you mind to hop in a zoom call and I can share my screen?

Answer (score 1):

To upload files you need to use contentType: "multipart/form-data".
Use the following as a reference to achieve the file upload.

helper function to create a instance with requied header. You may add any others to here.

```
const getInstance = () => {
  return axios.create({
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  });
}
```

call this method with the file to be uploaded

```
const fileUplaod = (file) => {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("images", file, file.name);
    
    getInstance()
      .post(endpoint_post_url, formData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("IMAGES_SUBMIT_SUCCESS");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("image submit error", err);
      });
}
```

check the request body in your backend code. You can upload multiple images as well to the same property. It will be an array in the request object.

Comment: @NathanNguyen, could you get it done? Let me know any problem you face with that. I'm happy to help.

Comment: Do I need onFileChange or just delete it ?

Comment: keep it. Just use the `imageSelected` instead of `file`. add a button to your UI and assign `fileUpload` as the `onClick` handler

Comment: Can you take a look my profileAPI. Did I write my route correct?

Comment: Nope, change `upload.single('profileImg')` as `upload.single('images')`. Or change the name as you want in `formData`.

Comment: I am having this error `TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230366/discussion-between-amila-senadheera-and-nathan-nguyen).

Comment: I joined the chat

Answer (score 0):

Edit the handleSubmit function to add a config to the axios call.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('profileImg', imageSelected);

    axios
      .post(`/upload`, formData, {
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
         }
      })
      .then(() => console.log("success"))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

Comment: Can you check my profileAPI code? did I write my routes right?